# "Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding" when building Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

```
to migrate your project. You may also pass the --ignore-deprecation flag to
ignore this check and continue with the deprecated v1 embedding. However,
the v1 Android embedding will be removed in future versions of Flutter.
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
The detected reason was:

  C:\Users\ALI HASSAN\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\arcore_app\example\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml uses
  `android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication"`
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 150):

You need to change the **android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml** file.

From :

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    ...
```

To :

```
<application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        ...
```

add this three lines if doesn't exist :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
          ...
```

This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java.

Comment: this is onlly  step 3 from Full-Flutter app migration https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects#full-flutter-app-migration

Answer (score 19):

**Change the android AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
...
 </application>
```

**TO**

```
android:name="${applicationName}"
```

Also added these two lines

```
<meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />
```

Answer (score 10):

Depending on what you're doing, you could choose to ignore the error.

I, for example, am following an online class which provides template code for each lesson. However, the template code is out of date and I do not really need to migrate it to proceed.

In Android Studio this can be achieved by adding the `--ignore-deprecation` flag to the 'Additional run args:' field: ie

From main menu, go to  Run ->Edit configurations then add--ignore -deprecation to the Additional run args field
[image: Ignore deprecation]

Answer (score 6):

If you left your project a long time ago and returned now, you have a few things to change, but they are simple if you know them:

**Manifest**
Change whatever you have written before here with:

```
<application android:name="${applicationName}"
```

add in **<application..**:

```
<application android:exported="true"...>
<meta-data
    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
    android:value="2" />..
```

In the main theme of the Activity main attention to correct with:

```
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="your theme" />
```

Hope you have the **kotlin** class as a reference, so you can go in the case of **MainActivity.kt**:

```
package com.yourpackage.....
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
 //If you have some native code put it back
}
```

If you have **Java** Activity Main:

```
package com.yourpackage.....

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
// You can keep this empty class or remove it.  
}
```

It is also worth updating **targetSdkVersion** and **compileSdkVersion**, in my case at: **31**

Answer (score 6):

just remove android platform and re-add android.

remove

```
rm -r android
```

add platform

```
flutter create --platforms=android .
```

Comment: Save your project before using this advice, because these commands will destroy your app....

Answer (score 3):

You can find the solution by creating a new project with the latest sdk and compare the two project's android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Imagine that you are on a production ambient and you suggest that to the manager.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml file.

From :

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    ...
```

To :

```
<application
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    ...
```

add this three lines if doesn't exist :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
    android:value="2" />
    ...
```

This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java.

Comment: Inside your code blocks decrease spaces and move all code closer to the left (use 4 spaces instead of 8)

Answer (score 2):

in Main Manifest.xml file ,

set android:exported = "false".

other Solution is ,

in app gradle ,

change Targetsdkversion to 30 and Compilesdkversion to 31

worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as the error tells you you're using a deprecated embedding version. To upgrade to a newer version please do the following :

1. Navigate to android/app/src/main/java/[your/package/name]/MainActivity.java open MainActivity.java or MainActivity.kt.
2. Delete the following dependencies

   ```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
   import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
   ```

and replace them with the following line

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
```

3. Open android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
4. Replace the reference to FlutterApplication in the application tag with ${applicationName} as following

   ```
    <application
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    >
    <!-- code omitted -->
    </application>
   ```

5.Remove all  tags with key android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame".
and Add a new  tag under application.

```
<meta-data
android:name="flutterEmbedding"
android:value="2" />
```

after that everything should be working fine

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the solution, you are looking for, but the only thing which worked for me is to change tflite dependency to tflite_flutter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and spent a lot of time on troubleshooting. It turned out that I had mistakenly deleted the `android/build.gradle` file from my project, and its absence was causing the error. Once I restored the file, the issue was resolved. So always double-check essential project files!.
May it help someone thanks...