# Unresolved package 'flutter'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-manifest

I download the flutter project from git hub start implementing in my android studio to learn but I get this problem in AndroidManifest.xml file only here and I also install all dependencies.
Please resolve my problem.
enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6UJm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oag8T.png)

Comment: I think you can ignore this. It want affect to run your app

Comment: Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding. I get this error during gradling.

Comment: have you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71457907/16974425

Comment: Thanks Bro I have no power to upvote another I will definetly give upvote you please support in future too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xm`l file.

From :

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

To :

```
<application
        android:name="${applicationName}"

 or

<application
        android:name="your_app_name"
```

add this three lines if does not exist :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the "android:name" in android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml file.

Make sure it's value is:
`"${applicationName}"`